# Prove that $\mathbb K[x] \times \mathbb K[y] \rightarrow \mathbb K[x,y] \,$ induces an isomorphism of $\mathbb K$-algebras.

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, algebras

I'm having some trouble with the following problem.

Let $x, y$ be two commuting variables, and let $\mathbb K$ a field. We define the following function $$\mathbb K[x] \times \mathbb K[y] \rightarrow \mathbb K[x,y], \, (P(x),Q(y))\mapsto P(x)Q(y).$$

I have two questions.

1.) I don't see why this function is bilinear.

2.) Why can we say that our function induces an  isomorphic $\mathbb K[x] \otimes \mathbb K[y] \rightarrow \mathbb K[x,y]?$

(For question 2., can we use the universal property of the tensor product?)

Comment: What do you mean by two functions being isomorphic?

Comment: Bilinearity is just the fact that polynomial multiplication distributes over addition.

Comment: @Randall how can I show that our function induces an isomorphism

Comment: I've made an edit is it more clear ?

Comment: One more:  an isomorphism of what?  Rings?  $\mathbb{K}$-vector spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question makes little sense. You also need to specify what kind of isomorphism. Of vector spaces over $\mathbb{K}$? As $\mathbb{K}$-algebras? As $\mathbb{Z}$-algebras (= rings)?

You can show that
$$\mathbb{K}[x] \otimes \mathbb{K}[y]\cong \mathbb{K}[x,y]$$ as $\mathbb{K}$-algebras.

I'll give a brief sketch. You can use the comments to ask for clarification if necessary.

Define the mapping
$$\mathbb{K}[x]  \times \mathbb{K}[y]\to \mathbb{K}[x,y]: (P(x), Q(y)) \mapsto P(x)Q(y)$$

This is a bilinear map by distributivity in $\mathbb{K}[x,y]$. The universal property of the tensor product gives a unique linear map
$$\mathbb{K}[x] \otimes \mathbb{K}[y] \to \mathbb{K}[x,y]: P(x) \otimes Q(y) \mapsto P(x)Q(y)$$

You have to show this map is a bijection and you will be done. Surjectivity ought to be clear, but you need to work a bit to show injectivity.

One possible approach (see the top comment for another approach): You can try to define an explicit inverse. For example, define
$$\mathbb{K}[x,y] \to \mathbb{K}[x] \otimes \mathbb{K}[y]$$
by $x \mapsto x \otimes 1$ and $y \mapsto 1 \otimes y$ and extend multiplicatively and linearly.

Comment: Another possibility, if this is indeed what OP wants to show: Prove that $\mathbb K[x,y]$ has the same universal property as the tensor product $\mathbb K[x]\otimes\mathbb K[y]$. Then the two are automatically isomorphic.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Indeed, that would work as well!

Comment: It is fun that you didn't mention your isomorphisms are as $K$-algebras. For me when learning it wasn't obvious that a tensor product gave a ring (algebra), not only a vector space / module.

Comment: @reuns Yes, you are right. It was implicit though (when I said extend multiplicatively and linearly).

Comment: Everything is pretty clear but can you give one more step just to see why it's bilinear please .. sorry if it's obvious

Comment: @EmmaFlora If $P ,Q,R$ are elements of $\mathbb{K}[x,y]$, do you see why $P(Q + R) = PQ + PR$?

Comment: yes sir thank you

Comment: @EmmaFlora Good! Now, we can consider $P(x) \in \mathbb{K}[x]$ and $Q(y), Q'(y) \in \mathbb{K}[y]$ as elements of $\mathbb{K}[x,y]$ and then the above implies $P(x)(Q(y) + Q'(y)) = P(x)Q(y) + P(x) Q'(y)$, right?

Comment: No problem with that yes

Comment: @EmmaFlora Well, that's one aspect of bilinearity right? Similarly, you can see that $(P(x)+P'(x))Q(y) = P(x) Q(y) + P'(x) Q(y)$ and this shows that we have additivity in each factor. Similar reasoning also shows that you can pull out scalars.

Comment: Perfectly clear to me now . thank you a lot sir @MathQED

Comment: You are very welcome!